# SaveChanges() is not modifying existing database record with updated data

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to update an existing record in my SQL database by calling _dbContext.SaveChanges(), but it is not updating the record with the new value I modify.

I have tried all other solutions I could find in reference to my issue, but none of them worked.

My code is as follows:

```
public int UpdateRank(Guid localId, int rank, Guid entityTypeId)
{            
    var result = _dbContext.EntityAttribute.FirstOrDefault(en => en.ParentGuid == localId && en.EntityAttributeTypeId == entityTypeId);
        result.IntValue = rank;
        return _dbContext.SaveChanges();            
    }
```

After finding a few solutions, I also tried adding

```
_dbContext.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

As well as

```
_dbContext.EntityAttribute.Attach(result);
```

before _dbContext.SaveChanges() to no avail.

If I have any of the previous sequences of code from these snippets preceding _dbContext.SaveChanges(), the code runs and does not throw an error but it does not update the record. If I add

```
_dbContext.EntityAttribute.Update(result);
```

And then call SaveChanges, I get the following error:
SqlException: Cannot update identity column 'ID'.

Where ID is a database generated bigint. I added both

```
_dbContext.EntityAttribute.Update(result).Property(en => en.Id).IsModified = false;
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

to the UpdateRank method and to the EntityAttribute database file in my data access project respectively and they made the code run with no error, but the record still was not updated after SaveChanges was called.

When I debug the code, I can see that the IntValue property on result has the first value I entered (4) every time it is retrieved, so it appears as though the dbContext is holding onto the result object. It just is not updating my database with the modified value. My database is also a remote database, it is not hosted on my local machine. I was unable to find anything that stated that might be a problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @mjwills it is neither. It's just a field in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to add more detail to your question, including the entity definition and/or EF entity type configuration for `EntityAttribute` including any attributes for mapping. Is "IntValue" mapped as a FK to another entity? This is the most probable cause for you not seeing updates.

For example, if EntityAttribute looks something like:

```
public class EntityAttribute
{
   // ... properties, key, etc.

   public int IntValue { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("IntValue")]
   public virtual IntAttribute MyInt { get; set; }
}
```

Then you run into a situation where there are 2 ways to point EntityAttribute at a new IntAttribute instance, and a bit of a chicken & egg scenario. If the record starts an IntValue of 4 and a MyInt with ID 4, changing it to "5" could be implied as either set IntValue to 5, or set MyInt to the entity with ID = 5. The second option is the correct one when you have a FK column defined:

```
public int UpdateRank(Guid localId, int rank, Guid entityTypeId)
{            
    var result = _dbContext.EntityAttribute.Single(en => en.ParentGuid == localId 
        && en.EntityAttributeTypeId == entityTypeId);
    var myInt = _dbContext.MyInts.Single(x => x.MyIntId == rank);
    result.MyInt = myInt;
    return _dbContext.SaveChanges();            
}
```

This is assuming the FK points to a reference property called "MyInt" with an entity DbSet called MyInts. Adopting a proper naming convention in your entities for Ids (PKs and FKs) will go a long way to making your code easier to understand.

Note I changed `FirstOrDefault` to `Single`. With Linq, use the most restrictive expected operation. Only use "OrDefault" if you expect the row(s) should either be available or not, and are handling the scenario where they are not. If you expect 1 row, use "Single" not "First". "First" is stating I expect many, but only care about the first, and it should always include an `OrderBy` clause.  This is to avoid potential bugs (updating the wrong record, ending up with NullReference Exceptions, etc.)

Now if you're sure there is no FK reference then try the below:

```
public int UpdateRank(Guid localId, int rank, Guid entityTypeId)
{            
    var result = _dbContext.EntityAttribute.Single(en => en.ParentGuid == localId 
         && en.EntityAttributeTypeId == entityTypeId);
    result.IntValue = rank;
    return _dbContext.SaveChanges();            

    var test = result.IntValue;
}
```

Put a breakpoint on the `var test = ...` line.
What is the value returned to `test`?  If the original IntValue is "4", rank is "5" and `test` comes back as "4" then something odd is definitely occuring. If `test` comes back as "5" then the database at that point should also report "5" and it's likely something else is resetting the value. With the breakpoint on that "test =" line after the SaveChanges, check the database with a manual query.  If the query cannot run with that breakpoint enabled, then another suspect would be that you are running within an open transaction, and the transaction is not being committed after this call. An open transaction would block the query execution until the Tx scope is completed. With transactions, the default action is to roll back any changes if it's not told to commit. If it didn't lock up and the DB shows "4" but `test` shows "5" then I'd be looking closely to ensure you're using `Single` not `FirstOrDefault` because this would look like a bug where you're querying one record in the DB, but EF is picking a different one. (i.e. You expect 1 record, but there are multiple that match the criteria.) Using `Single` will raise an exception in this case to the effect that 1 record was expected, but multiple returned.

Comment: I added the test section you asked for, and test is indeed coming back with a value of "6" if I set the field to 6, while the initial value of IntValue from result is 4 before I modify it.

My IntValue field is not a FK, the following is the entity definition: 
public double? IntValue { get; set; }. I will try the Single option instead and let you know what I find.

Comment: Ok, interesting, with that breakpoint also query your database with SSMS or applicable client tool and check that record to see if the DB says 4 or 6. If the query stalls, you likely have an open transaction. If the DB says 6, something is reverting it, if the DB says 4, we have a mystery. :) (Possibly a mismatch on the connection string? do other table values get updated successfully?)

Comment: Single did not do anything different than my FirstOrDefault call. In our database, the query I am using can only match to one record, no matter what since the localID is a distinct GUID. In the database, the record I am trying to update currently has an IntValue of 0, and I want to change it to 4. The database still reflects the 0 value, even though from dbcontext it shows 4 after it retrieves the "result" object. Of note, I found another method that adds a note to the same entity, and it uses the Add() method. This works, and I can see the new note in the database after the call.

Comment: Ok, "mystery" it is. Can you please append your question to include the entire entity definition (class) and any configuration you use relative to that class? (EntityTypeConfiguration, or code in the DbContext's OnModelCreating method.

Comment: Also, can you confirm what Database engine you are connecting to, and the data type of this field in the table, and the property in your entity? You mention Nullable<Double> in the comment above, but the property is named "IntValue"? (and set to a variable called "rank") If you are renaming fields etc. from your system it would help to keep examples as close to the real code as possible. Attempts to obfuscate an example can mislead or hide a root cause.